# SQL Query for summation of a difference

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the total spending by customers (and their industry types) as (Invoice total- Credit Memo). I tried doing this as a summation of the difference in the SELECT statement with a GROUP BY Cust. Code. But this doesn't work at all. Where am I going wrong

```
SELECT "CardCode", 
       "CardName", 
       "IndName", 
       (OINV."DocTotal" - ORIN."DocTotal") AS InvoiceTotal 
GROUP BY "CardCode"
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: For starters, you aren't specifying a `FROM` clause.  Secondly, you need to use `SUM()` to get the summation, and lastly, you *must* group by all non-aggregated columns in your query (e.g. `CardCode`, `CardName`, and `IndName`)

Comment: Which error are you seeing? But yes, as Siyual pointed out, where are you selecting your data from?

Comment: I can't see any FROM clause.

Comment: I don't see a sum function in the code.

Comment: I have a FROM Clause in my query of course.. I just showed here what I though I had problem with. Including the FROM here:        
 
SELECT T0."CardCode", T0."CardName", T1."IndName", SUM(T2."DocTotal" - T3."DocTotal") AS InvoiceTotal 
 
FROM OCRD T0  JOIN OOND T1 ON T0."IndustryC" = T1."IndCode" 
 JOIN OINV T2 ON T0."CardCode" = T2."CardCode" 
 JOIN ORIN T3 ON T0."CardCode" = T3."CardCode"
 
 
GROUP BY T0."CardCode"

Comment: Siyual, Thanks, I grouped by all non-aggregated columns, and I still don't get a result. It doesn't show me any error, but just returns nothing.